# Difficulty receiving an HTTP Response from API -- Bad Request Error

Tags: c#, json, wpf, serialization, http-headers

I'm attempting to pass username/password from an application to the API to receive a token authorization key. When I attempt to do so, I receive a 400 Bad Request error and I cannot figure out why. Below is the method in question:

```
public User UserAuthentication(string username, string password)
{
    string endpoint = baseURL + "/TOKEN";

    // Could be POST maybe
    string method = "POST";

    Credential jsonObj = new Credential
                         {
                            grant_type = "password",
                            username = username,
                            password = password
                         };

    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObj);

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    //x - www - form - urlencoded
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x - www - form - urlencoded";
    wc.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
    wc.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Bearer <token>";
    wc.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");

    string header = wc.Headers.ToString();

    try
    {
        string response = wc.UploadString(endpoint, method, jsonStr);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've messed around altering just about everything in this method in search of a fix.

What I've done:

- /TOKEN was /values & /api/values
- POST method was GET -- With this, I received a "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." error.
- ContentType was changed to "application/json"
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin had the baseURL
- Checked the format of header & body:

Header:

```
{Content-Type: application/x - www - form - urlencoded
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS}
```

Body:

```
{"grant_type":"password",
"username":"test@gmail.com",
"password":"password123"}
```

I obviously have something wrong in my request, I've just run out of ideas to try. I'm not entirely sure if UploadString() is the correct method to be using in this situation, but I couldn't find another method in the WebClient class that would be better. Any help to try and push me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: it's not `application/x - www - form - urlencoded`, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Why are you using `Add` in some cases and the index operator in others for your headers?

Comment: I'll try removing the spaces. I used Add in the instances where it didn't have the property that I wanted to add.
-- Fixed the spaces but still no luck getting through.

Comment: So you are trying to post JSON data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but JSON data isn't "form url encoded", it's `application/json`.

Comment: I have tried both, and continually switch the values for each iteration. JSON was my original thought, but through postman, the response is urlencoded; so I've been trying both.
--- both values receive a response through postman.

Comment: I'll add an answer. i think i know what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I think you are trying to do is a form-urlencoded post to a "token" endpoint with a username/password grant. These are typically done like so:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://example.com/token"))
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "password" },
        { "username", "username@site.com" },
        { "password", "password12345" }
    })
})
{
    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(request))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        //await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<BearerToken>();
        // for testing purposes, try this:
        var returnData = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(returnData);
    }
}
```

You should define this outside all scopes where you need to do Http requests:

```
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
```

So, first off, try to stick with `HttpClient`. Other patterns such as `WebClient` are considered legacy.

Next, CORS headers are typically returned from the server when an OPTIONS call is sent to the server. You aren't doing that here, and you should never have to worry about that kind of stuff inside a C# program running from your computer. So you can drop the access-control header stuff.

Form-urlencoded data is not JSON data. It's a different way to format data. If you want to send JSON data, you should use the content-type `application/json`

Finally, you are trying to add an `Authorization` header. But that doesn't make much sense as you are trying to authenticate yourself to *become* authorized. If you send the right username/password, you will receive a bearer token that you can use in an `Authorization` header for future requests to said service.

Oh and I forgot to add: Whenever you see an error in the [400,499] range (in this case "400 - bad request") it means that *you* sent something wrong and the server doesn't understand what you are trying to do. For example: a 401 means you sent invalid or missing authorization information. A 400 means your data was probably malformed.

But I like your question... I can see what you were doing and you tried all kinds of different things.

Download a program called `Fiddler` if you want to see how HTTP works. It's a great tool to debug your HTTP calls.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am rather new to this, this is my first project out of school. The headers were problems I ran into previously and just kind of stuck them in there to be safe. I appreciate you taking the time to not only offer a solution but to address what I had wrong and explain why it was wrong. This should set me in the right direction.

Comment: @Dan -- does your school require you to use the `WebClient` object? If so, I could change it over to use that. I don't usually like doing people's homework... but I could get you going.

Comment: @Dan -- nevermind -- re-read it and this is outside of school :)